# LaTeX formula with columns

Tags: latex

Based on info from this source - http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics.

I tried to have 3 columns in equation:

```
<math>
\begin{align}
f(x) & = h(&x, y)\\
& = G(&x, y,\\
& &z)
\end{align}
</math>
```

to have x and z aligned, but it is not aligned...

[image: f(x) & = G(&x, y, & &z)]

I'm rying with [wikipedia sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Sandbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an `array` to properly achieve multiple alignment points. Also, some spacing adjustments (`\!` is a negative math space) make the display look better:

[image]

```
<math>
\begin{array}{rll}
  f(x) &\!\!\! = h(&\!\!\!\! x, y) \\
       &\!\!\! = G(&\!\!\!\! x, y, \\
       &\!\!\!     &\!\!\!\! z)
\end{array}
</math>
```

Comment: Please add the comment next time, otherwise I'm not notified. Thenks you ;-)